# Stuck on NodeJS mongoDB find() Query

Tags: node.js, json, mongoose, postman

I am unable to write the correct query.
I am trying to check if the user already exists in the database and it will respond in Login Successfully Response.
This code is in working position problem lies in Query.
I hope somebody will help

```
function login() {
    app.post("/login/", async(req, res) => {

        const query = new Model({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
        });
        const cursor = Model.find(query);  // (*Here's the problem*)
        console.log(cursor);
 if (query === cursor) {**strong text**
            console.log(query);
            res.send("login successfully");
        } else {
            console.log(query);
            res.send("user does not exist ");
        }
    });
}

login();

// Model and Schema

const LoginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
});
const Model = mongoose.model("login_details", LoginSchema);

// Registeration Phase
function registration() {
    app.post("/register/", async(req, res) => {
        const model = new Model({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
        });
        const result = await model.save();
        console.log(result);
        res.send(model);
    });
}

// Headers

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extend: true }));

//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues with your code

1- You don't need to use `new Model({})` to query

2- You're using `.find()` which returns an array, use `findOne()` instead

3- You're attempting to check if a mongoose model (with `_id`) equals a query without the `_id` which won't work

4- Use return at the end of your function (won't affect the functionality here but just as good practice not to encounter errors like `cannot set headers after they're sent`)

possible solution

```
function login() {
  app.post("/login/", async (req, res) => {

    const cursor = await Model.findOne({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
    });
    console.log(cursor);
    if (cursor) {
      console.log(cursor);
      return res.send("login successfully");
    } else {
      return res.send("user does not exist ");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Mongoose in the wrong way. Try this.

```
const result = await Model.find({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });
```